# Homegrown authentication, how do I remember and get the logged in user

Tags: jsf, authentication

I made a filter and a authentication in an application JSF it works very well but I'd like get the current user and I have no idea how to do that.
anybody could help me?

This method authenticates

```
public String Authenticates() {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    EntityManager manager = getManager();
    PersonDAO dao = new PersonDAOJPA(manager);

    if (dao.login(getPerson().getEmail(), getPerson().getPassword())) {
        ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) ec.getSession(false);
        session.setAttribute("userLogged", true);
        getCurrentUser();
        return "/index.xhtml" + "?faces-redirect=true";
    } else {
        FacesMessage ms = new FacesMessage("Email or Password Incorrect");
        ms.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        fc.addMessage(null, ms);
        return "/account.xhtml";
    }
}
```

Comment: You're creating a session attribute called "userLogged" to indicate that there is a logged user in this session. You could also create an attribute named "currentUser" where you could insert the user's email or id, for instance. Then when you want to check the current user, all you'd have to do is to check this parameter.

Comment: Or even better, use a `@SessionScoped` bean for your user and inject it in other managed beans where you need it.

Comment: Thanks man. Have I to use the same method, setAttribute?

Comment: No. It is a separate bean just decorated (annotated) with `@SessionScoped` where you can declare any members of your interest. Doing so, you will also get rid of exposing the underlying `HttpSession` unnecessarily as you are currently doing.

Comment: Could you give me an example? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically setting a boolean in session to indicate if an user is logged in or not.

```
if (userService.login(email, password)) {
    session.setAttribute("userLogged", true);
}
```

This is rather simplistic. This can be improved by simply putting the user itself in the session.

```
User user = userService.find(email, password);

if (user != null) {
    session.setAttribute("user", user);
}
```

Now, wherever you'd like to check if an user is logged in, instead of checking if `userLogged` equals `true`, you just check if `user` does not equal `null`.

```
User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");

if (user != null) {
    // User is logged in.
} else {
    // User is not logged in.
}
```

This immediately solves your problem of getting the "current" user. It's this way already available by `#{user}`.

```
<p>Your email is #{user.email}.</p>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you'd better not grab the raw `HttpSession` from under JSF's covers in a JSF artifact. That `false` argument in `getSession(false)` is also another thinking mistake and prone to `NullPointerException` later on. Instead, use `ExternalContext#getSessionMap()`.

```
context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("user", user);
```